# Formatting NSArray for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I have trouble formatting the NSArray

```
let temp = json.value(forKeyPath: "data.current_condition.temp_F") as Any
                                                  
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.setWeather(temp: temp as! NSArray  )
                              }
func setWeather(  temp: NSArray) {
          TempLabel.text = "\(temp)"
```

When I run the program TempLabel only shows " ( " because it's in NSArray form. I am not sure how do I get rid of "(".

Comment: please explain. your problem clearly

Comment: @nivritgupta thanks for feedback. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the description of the object to show it on the UI is quite fragile, and could change anytime internally in iOS.

What I would try instead is to cast the result of your json value into Swift types. In your case `[Int]` should work. Then use one of the collection methods to convert the Int array to String.

Try something like this:

```
let temp = json.value(forKeyPath: "data.current_condition.temp_F") as! [Int]
TempLabel.text = temp.map({ "\($0)" }).joined(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: Thanks you. I have trouble to understand map function, so .map({ "\($0)" }) resprent every value in array and .joined(separator: ", ") is insert comma if [[1,2],[1.2] then [1,2,1,2]. But how does it work in this case?

Comment: `map` basically takes the elements of an array and transforms them using a method. In our case Int -> String using string interpolation: "\($0)" ([1, 2, 3] -> ["1", "2", "3"]). `joined` is another method that joins the elements of a string array using a separator (["1", "2", "3"] -> ", ").